# One USB device, two serial interfaces: how to?

Tags: usb, serial-port

I have a serial device that should be exposed as two serial ports: /dev/ttyACM0 and /dev/ttyACM1.

Currently I only get the first one despite the same unit under Windows exposes as the expected two serials.
My dmesg reports this:

```
[ 2738.788150] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 2738.876575] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=152a, idProduct=8230
[ 2738.876584] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2738.876590] usb 2-1.2: Product: Septentrio USB Device
[ 2738.876594] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Septentrio
[ 2738.941229] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 2738.942171] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[ 2738.942174] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN
```

While `lsusb -vvv` says [this](http://pastebin.com/WVsh5pdB).

The relevant part from /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices is this:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=02 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=12   MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=02(comm.) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  2
P:  Vendor=152a ProdID=8230 Rev= 1.10
S:  Manufacturer=Septentrio  
S:  Product=Septentrio USB Device
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 2 Atr=c0 MxPwr=  2mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=02(comm.) Sub=02 Prot=ff Driver=
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=ff Driver=
E:  Ad=01(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=02(comm.) Sub=02 Prot=ff Driver=
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=ff Driver=
E:  Ad=04(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=85(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
C:* #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=  2mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(comm.) Sub=02 Prot=01 Driver=cdc_acm
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  64 Ivl=1ms
I:* If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=cdc_acm
E:  Ad=01(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
```

Here my device (a GPS modem) is `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 152a:8230 Thesycon Systemsoftware & Consulting GmbH`.

I thought that the cdc_acm module had some option to be used with modprobe/insmod, but it seems it's not easy to find anything about it.

How can I have both serial ports recognized/created/enabled under Ubuntu?
TIA.

[UPDATE] I have also found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508304/usb-communications-device-with-multiple-serial-ports-working-on-all-platforms) tightly linked to mine. But have no idea on how to implement the suggested changes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Also please add output of `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices | awk '/8230/' RS=`

Comment: The device is mounted inside a crane and I need to book an hour in order to disconnect the unit from Windows controller and run that command from Linux.  Maybe next week. Anyway, under Windows 7 I get those two serial ports (COM15 and COM16), under Linux just one (ttyACM0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution requires you to load of a kernel module, namely drivers/usb/serial/option.ko and to ask udev to apply some changes as soon as the device gets recognized (switch to the second configuration and enable the serial driver for the specific device). So:

1. Have the `option.ko` module loaded at boot
2. Create a brand new udev rule like this very one:

   ```
   SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{product}=="Septentrio USB Device", ATTR{bConfigurationValue}="2", PROGRAM+="/bin/bash -c \"/bin/echo $VENDOR $PRODUCT > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id\""
   ```

Comment: udev only. This of course won't work with other software.

Comment: Yeah, but it is still a partial solution for others, atleast they know that `option.ko` module should be loaded somehow.